# What to look for when comparing processors?

Tags: cpu

Of course from benchmark testing what is the hierarchy when comparing processors?

I always assumed:

Brand
Generation
Nano meters
Cores
Clock rate
Intergrated graphics
TDP

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: One person's perfect processor may not be suitable for another. Comparing processors depends on how you use it, therefore, entirely opinion when comparing unless you're comparing a specific capability.

Answer (score 3):

There are no universal indicators of performance.

- Within the same generation / family then Clock Speed is a good indicator.
- Generation may be a good indicator, although the latest often cost more and have less performance per dollar
- Memory bandwidth with modern Intel and AMD processor, because the memory controller is now on the CPU the motherboard does not decide max speed of RAM access.
- More cores does not necessarily mean better performance for all processes or applications
- Die Size has more to do with TDP than speed
- TDP is not a performance metric, it is a measurement of power and heat

If you are shopping for a processor, then the hierarchy should really look more like:

1. What applications will I use, and do they benefit more from Clock Speed, or more cores
2. Do the applications have a performance gain with AMD or Intel Architecture
3. What is the budget
4. Do the applications benefit from GPU acceleration, hence cut some $$$ from the CPU and move to the GPU
5. Benchmarks for applications, does the latest generation significantly outperform the previous?